# Contacts' "profile" entries (social media links) don't appear in iOS

Tags: macos, ios, contacts, links, contacts.app

I have links to my contacts' social media profiles (e.g. Facebook, LinkedIn) saved on the Mac copy of my contacts. They are saved as copies of URLs (e.g. 'http://www.domain.ext/nym') pasted into the "profile" entries at the end of each card. These are synced over to my iOS device via USB and iTunes.

When I view contacts on the iOS device, the profiles aren't listed. Items that do sync over are photo, name, phones, emails, URLs, addresses, anniversaries, relationships, and notes (everything except profile links).

- Mac OS X 9.5 Mavericks
- iOS 8.1.1
- iTunes 12.0.1.26
- No iCloud.
- No third-party sync.

Comment: works over iCloud

Comment: You could always go back to sneaker-net; that's pretty secure...

Comment: I can't test, because it works perfectly over iCloud - the data's there before I can get to my iPhone address book, if I enter it on the Mac.

Comment: Can you provide sample vCards from both sides?